# How does lazy loading variable work using inner classes in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, lazy-loading, inner-classes

I am trying to understand the following code snippet that apparently is a lazy-loading example of the `singleton` attribute in the `LazyHolder` class.

```java
class Singleton {
  // My private inner class containing my future lazy loading attribute
  private static class LazyHolder {
    private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
  }

  public static Singleton getSingleton() {
    return LazyHolder.singleton;
  }
}
```

```java
class Main {
  public static main(String[] args) {
    Singleton s = Singleton.getSingleton();
  }
}
```

According to some online courses I have been following, the `private static singleton` instance will be created at the line:

```java
Singleton s = Singleton.getSingleton()
```

But since the `singleton` attribute is `static`, I thought it's created during the `LazyHolder` class definition. So my question is:

When is the `LazyHolder` class really created?

- is it created when the `Singleton` class is created, because `LazyHolder` is an attribute of `Singleton` class, or
- is it created when we enter in the `getSingleton()` method of `Singleton` class?

I would really appreciate an explanation of what's happening during the runtime execution.

Comment: Don't write many questions in one post. Focus only on single problem that you want to get answer.

Comment: First of all, hello and thank you for your response. By asking multiple questions, I am just trying to detail and  share explicitly my way of thinking. Didnt you just see I said I was new to this ? By downgrading my post, you are just pulling me down and not up

Comment: Since you are new here, I recommend you to read [How to ask a question](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Hulk thank you for your response. Not really, because I dont understand why the LazyHolder class would be created during the method call. In fact the java compiler should normally see that the LazyHolder class is used somewhere in the code, so the compiler, when building  the byte codes, should put some instructions like :" load the LazyHolder class before starting the main execution" ..

Comment: It's the opposite.  The Java language specification requires that classes are not loaded until they are used at run time.  So the Java compiler is expressly forbidden from "seeing that the LazyHolder class is used ... load(ing) the LazyHolder class before starting the main execution."  The JVM is *required* to wait until the class is actually invoked or referenced in some way at run time, then the class is loaded.

Comment: @markspace oh okay I see now, I didnt know that thank you a lot ! Does it work the same for all compilers like in C/C++, ADA etc. ?

Comment: No, most compilers are the opposite of Java.  Check the language spec of whatever you are using.

Comment: The duplicate linked by Hulk does answer your question, see the topvoted answer: _"The JVM defers initializing the InstanceHolder class until it is actually used,"_